# auto completion feature in aptana studio

Tags: html, aptana

I am new user of aptana studio. I have installed just today.
As in dreamweaver there is autocompletion tag feature like:

```
<test></test>
```

when we do `"</"`, it auto completes as `</test>`.

How can i do the same with aptana studio?

Answer (score 0):

Window->preferences->Aptana Studio->Editors->HTML, select 'automatically insert closing tags' should work for you?

Personally I feel comfortable enough with the display proposals above that.